# Can only run AutoCAD 2010 or 2011 when debugging from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, autocad

I've noticed recently that AutoCAD gets slower and slower after as I debug it, close, then debug again.  In addition AutoCAD just freezes when I try to open it without debugging (in or out of visual studio).  Has anybody else ran into this problem before and what is the solution?

Comment: Why are you debugging AutoCAD? Isn't that AutoDesk's job?

Comment: I would assume he is debugging an ObjectArx or .NET plugin for AutoCAD. This is a typical activity.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity.  I am debugging a .NET plugin for AutoCAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching around for a while I noticed that the WSCommCntr1.exe process (AutoDesk Communication Center) was showing up multiple times.  I assume that it is spawning a new version of this process each time I debug.  To fix this and speed AutoCAD up in general, I disable this process from starting using this fix that I found.

http://otb.manusoft.com/2009/03/disable-infocenter-in-autocad-2010.htm